# How to return full JSON of Tweet from Twitter Gem Twitter Object

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb, twitter

So I have some code:

```
#twitter api access config up here
Twitter.status(27558893223)
```

and I know I get all the tweet information from that Twitter.status line. What I want though isn't a Ruby object. I want the full JSON of that tweet so I can directly use it in populating my mongodb instance. Can I get some help on how to convert that tweet object into just JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly depends what all columns you want to populate in your DB. The doc [here](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet) mentions pretty good info on what all elements you can fetch from `Twitter::Tweet`.

For instance you can do things like mentioned below and store it accordingly to your DB instance.

```
Twitter.status(27558893223).source
Twitter.status(27558893223).from_user
Twitter.status(27558893223).from_user_id 
Twitter.status(27558893223).lang
```

Or you could do `Twitter.status(27558893223).attrs` and handle the JSON accordingly.

Let me know if I understood the question wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you use [JSON.generate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-generate) method on `Tweet.attrs`?

Answer (score 2):

For one object of class **Twitter::Tweet** use **.attrs**

> Twitter.status(27558893223).attrs

For array of objects use **.map(&:attrs)**

> Twitter.user_timeline("[someone's twitter name]").map(&:attrs)

Here is a simple Sinatra app to return tweets of Katy Perry :)

`require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/jsonp'
require 'twitter'`

class TwitterFetcher < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::Jsonp

@@twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key       = ENV['consumer_key']
    config.consumer_secret    = #ENV['consumer_secret']
    # config.bearer_token       = ENV['bearer_token']
    config.access_token        = # ENV['access_token']
    config.access_token_secret = #ENV['access_token_secret']
  end

get '/' do
    result = @@twitter_client.user_timeline("katyperry")
    jsonp result.map(&:attrs)
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this didn't exist before.

Just call `.to_json` øn the tweet object:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)
client.status(27558893223).to_json
```